# I'm trying to make a simple API call using JavaScript/TypeScript and get any data to return properly. The API is formatted in XML

Tags: javascript, json, xml, typescript, api

I'm trying to get started on a project that requires the calling of an api which is formatted in xml, and I can't get any data to display.

I've been trying to use both javascript and typescript to make an HTTP request, I've also tried using fetch. I'm not sure if I'm just not using the right code.

```
httpModule.request({
    url: "http://api.rideuta.com/SIRI/SIRI.svc/VehicleMonitor/ByRoute?route=3&onwardcalls=true&usertoken=UTBPQBLBFV7",
    method: "GET"
}).then((res) => {
    // Argument (response) is HttpResponse
    console.log(res);
}, (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});

I'm just trying to get basic data to return or display.
```

Comment: NodeJS or browser? What is `httpModule` ? Have you looked up the docs of that API?

Comment: my project is a NativeScript project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can read in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) httpResponse needs to be converted to text or json with calling `.text()` or `.json()` on it